# JSON-data to WebMethod using jQuery returning errors

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm trying to send a json list populated with the id's from the 'data-seq' attribute only when the 'value' == true.

I have tried out a lot solution but it keeps getting me error messages, the most common are "there is no parameterless constructor for the type string" when using string[] or "string is not supported for deserialization of an array" when using string as code-behind parameter in the WebMethod.

```
function sentData() {        
    var json = [];
    $('.btn[value="true"]').each(function () {
        var obj = {
            id: $(this).attr("data-seq")
        };
        json.push(obj);
    });
    json = JSON.stringify({ jsonList: json });
    console.log(json); // {"jsonList":[{"id":"38468"},{"id":"42443"},{"id":"42444"}]} (the right id's are getting stored)

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "Default.aspx/getList",
        dataType: "json",
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('bad, ' + errorThrown + ", " + jqXHR.responseText + ", " + textStatus);
        },
        success: function(json){
            //do something with the result
        }
    });
    return false;
}

// Code-Behind
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public static void getList(string jsonList)
{
    // string: string is not supported for deserialization of an array
    // string[]: there is no parameterless constructor for the type string
}
```

Comment: I think you should not accept it as string since your structure will be a `list` with some type of structure inside it like `{"jsonList":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"7"}]}`.. Example from **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/wq0tr7k9/)**

Comment: If you're just sending ids why don't you POST a list of strings? `["1","2","3"]`

Comment: If I use List<String> jsonList it is also not working. The list of strings look like a good idea, can you make an answer with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You are just sending IDs so send them as comma-separated string like this:

```
function sentData() {        
    var json = [];
    $('.btn[value="true"]').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-seq")
        json.push(id);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "Default.aspx/getList",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{jsonList: "' + json + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('bad, ' + errorThrown + ", " + jqXHR.responseText + ", " + textStatus);
        },
        success: function(json){
            //do something with the result
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And Code-Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public static void getList(string jsonList)
{
    List<string> ListOfIDs = jsonList.Split(',').ToList();
}
```